# How do I raise alert message in multiple file uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple selects, where in case user selects same file twice I should display alert message saying that "This file has been already selected". In the example below, file is not added (which is ok) but the alert box does not popup.

```
$.fn.fileUploader = function(filesToUpload) {
    this.closest(".files").change(function(evt) {
                        var index;
                        for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
                            index = filesToUpload.indexOf(evt.target.files[i]);
                            if (index > -1) {
                                filesToUpload.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        }
                        for (i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
                            var filename = evt.target.files[i].name;
                            var valid_extensions = /(\.pdf|\.doc|\.docx)$/i;                            
                            if (valid_extensions.test(filename)) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
                                    filesToUpload.push(evt.target.files[i]);
                                };
                                var output = [];
                                for (var i = 0, f; f = evt.target.files[i]; i++) {
                                    var removeLink = "<a class=\"removeFile\" href=\"#\" data-fileid=\""+ i + "\">Remove</a>";
                                    output.push("<li><strong>", escape(f.name),"</strong> - ", removeLink,"</li> ");
                                }
                                $(this).children(".fileList").append(output.join(""));
                            } else {
                                alert('Invalid File');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
};

var filesToUpload = [];
$(document).on("click", ".removeFile", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fileName = $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
    // loop through the files array and check if the name of that file matches
    // FileName
    // and get the index of the match
    for (i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i) {
        if (filesToUpload[i].name == fileName) {
            // console.log("match at: " + i);
            // remove the one element at the index where we get a match
            filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    // console.log(filesToUpload);
    // remove the <li> element of the removed file from the page DOM
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#files1").fileUploader(filesToUpload);
$("#files2").fileUploader(filesToUpload);

$("#uploadBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Post the HTML in your question. Also visit [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting next question.